# Order of columns returned in ResultSet

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I have a Java program reading data from an Access database where the table is created dynamically each time, and the number of columns varies depending on the data populated.

The table has columns as shown below. Only columns `RowID` and `StatusOfProcessing` are fixed and will be at the end.

```
column1,column2,column3, ... columnN,RowID,StatusOfProcessing
```

Below is piece of code

```
String str = "SELECT TOP 50 * FROM Dynamic_table WHERE StatusOfProcessing='0'";
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(str);
```

When reading data from the ResultSet, does it always have columns in the order listed above, or should I use

```
String str = "SELECT TOP 50 column1,column2,column3 .... columnN,RowID,StatusOfProcessing FROM Dynamic_table WHERE StatusOfProcessing='0'";
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(str);
```

Can someone clarify?

Comment: It will return the fields in the order you created them if you use * . if you want them in a different order you need to specify them in the specific order. This should have been easy for you to test for yourself... No?

Answer (score 4):

`SELECT *` will normaly return columns in the order in which they were created, e.g., the order in which they appeared in the `CREATE TABLE` statement. However, bear in mind that in addition to retrieving the value of a column by its *index*, as in

```java
int col1value = resultSet.getInt(1);
```

you can also retrieve the value in a given column by referring to its *name*, as in

```java
int col1value = resultSet.getInt("column1");
```

Furthermore, if you need to see the actual order of the columns or verify the names and types of the columns in a ResultSet you can use a [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) object to get that information.